# Tooltips for tags when editing a question

Tags: feature-request, support

When editing a question some authors will place various almost random tags associated with a question, and I would often like to clear out excess tags or irrelivant tags (along with general question improvement).

However unlike the question when being "Viewed", on the edit screen there is no tooltip hover info for the contents of a tag, and adding new tags will not repeat already mentioned tags, so for instance I just edited a question with the tag `mysql` and the question was about PDO, so I wanted to check that the `mysql` tag was relevant, as in if the tag itself mentioned

> "for PDO queries use the PDO tag"

*(the type of direction many of SO tags **do** have)*

It seems I can't read the information of a tag unless I delete it from a question and then retype it, this is clearly deeply inefficient and leaves a very large area for human failure (deleting a correct tag and then forgetting to readd it, etc.) just to be able to read the tag contents.

I'm afraid I am unlikely to memorise the summary contents of every tag on Stack OVerflow.

As I (and I suspect many of us) edit questions for a wide variety of reasons it's also somewhat impractical to have to remember to check and hover each question's tag before editing the question. The editing of tags is not usually the primary reason I edit the question.

**So:

Can chosen tags displayed on the "edit question" dialog please show the tag tooltip details for the chosen tag, as it does for when the question is viewed or first written.**

Comment: Apologies, I intended to post this on Meta.StackOverflow.com rather than StackExchange.